# Progressbar in a function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Hi guys so i have this function that do a tracert in python.
I want to insert a progress bar because take some time to execute the commmand.
I tried but didin't work.
Any good soul can help ?

```
def tracertapp():  
    def tracert1(x):
        trc= f"tracert {x}"
        result1 = subprocess.check_output(f"{trc}", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)     
        print(result1)
    
    ip = input("Insert the ip: ")
    tracert1(ip)
tracertapp()
```

I just want a progress bar in this wile load the information.
Thanks for helping.
I'm just new in  Python.

Answer (score 0):

u can use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), its very simple and u can use it perfect for ur project.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
...
```

Comment: Where i use in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the proglog package.

It has default progress bar as well as lets you come up with custom ones.

Its really easy to implement aswell.

Comment: Where i use in the code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).